# Determine if outermost scope in string is a function in JavaScript language agnosticlly

Tags: javascript, regex

The reason I say language agnostic is that I would like a small, self contained implementation that determines if the outermost scope in a string containing JavaScript is a function or not. I've looked at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) for guidance on the possible forms of declaring functions, but unfortunately wasn't able to find any comprehensive examples for all the ways functions can be defined in JS.

Here's a few different test cases the implementation should be able to handle:

```js
// yes
function (){}

//yes
() => p

//yes
((g) => p)

//yes
(g => p)

//no
(()=>p)()).call()

//no
a = function (){
  console.log()
{

//no
g=() => p
```

I've thought about trying to construct a regex to look for this, but I'm not sure I've covered every case, and I haven't found any sort of corpus of example JS functions, or even if a pure regex approach would be the best way to handle this.

Comment: `function (){}` is invalid syntax, standalone. Will that actually occur, or will such functions always have names, eg `function foo` for a function declaration? Or are all such strings here going to be interpreted as the expression part of a function expression assigned to a variable, in which `foo = function (){}` is valid?

Comment: "`function (){}` is invalid syntax, standalone" Interesting, I was unaware of the fact. However within this specific context it would be considered valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/tree/master/acorn) to parse the Javascript. If parsing is successful, and the body is composed only of a single item, and that item is a `FunctionDeclaration` or `ArrowFunctionExpression`, the test passes:

```js
const test = (str) => {
  console.log(str);
  try {
    const { body } = acorn.parse(str);
    if (body.length > 1) throw new Error();
    const [item] = body;
    if (item.type === 'FunctionDeclaration' || (item.type === 'ExpressionStatement' && item.expression.type === 'ArrowFunctionExpression')) {
      console.log('Pass');
    } else {
      console.log('invalid');
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('invalid');
  }
};

// function (){}

test(`function foo() {}`);
test(`() => p`);
test(`((g) => p)`);
test(`(g => p)`);
test(`(()=>p)()).call()`);
test(`a = function (){
  console.log()
{`);
test(`g=() => p`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/acorn/7.1.1/acorn.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was one of the solutions I considered, unfortunately it doesn't satisfy my 'self contained' requirement.